# How can I take two numbers and add, multiply, subtract or divide them?

Tags: python

So far I have this I'm trying to add on to it but I don't know what to put

```
first  = raw_input('Enter 1st number: ')
second = raw_input('Enter 2nd number: ')
third  = raw_input('Enter *,/,+,-')
```

Comment: You mean a *calculator*?

Comment: Yea i think so i'm no that much of a programer i'ts actually pycharm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a dictionary of the tokens and their corresponding operators:

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, div

lookup = {'+': add, '-': sub, '*': mul, '/': div}

print lookup[third](int(first), int(second))
```

(see [`operator`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html))

You might want to check if `third` is a key in the dictionary first (i.e. `third in lookup`), but the overall idea remains the same.

Comment: Thank you it work just the way i needed it to